# No output on file

Tags: c, file, output

For some reason my code does not output anything on my file.
Below is the relevant code. If you need me to provide more, please say so.

```
    //Opening file
    fopen("output.txt", "w");

    if (output_Ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Output file could not be opened.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(output_Ptr, "Solution vector\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            fprintf(output_Ptr, "x[%d]=%10.5f\n", i, x[i]);
        }
        fprintf(output_Ptr, "\n");
    }


    fclose(output_Ptr);

    //free memory
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(a[i]);
    }
    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to store file descriptor returned by the `fopen` which is the reference pointer for accessing you file to perform any file operations.

Solution:

change

`fopen("output.txt", "w");`

To

```
output_Ptr = fopen("output.txt", "w");
```

Answer (score 2):

Compiler is not magic, it cannot guess what you want to do. Update the very first line of your code in the question this way:

```
output_Ptr = fopen("output.txt", "w");
```

If you don't store the result from fopen, you won't get a handle to your file and there is no way using output_Ptr will gives something.

Comment: How do I do that? First time, sorry.

Comment: @David_red you update your code with the line I wrote. You don't see the difference with the code in your question?

Comment: Terribly sorry. No sleep last night. Thank you.